# Using rbind and lapply to conditionally copy rows between two dataframes with identical columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe, apply, lapply, rbind

I have read through other stackoverflow questions on this topic, but I'm still lost. I think I need to use lapply, but I'm failing to see exactly how to do it.

Let's say I have the following two dataframes:

```
df1 <- data.frame(Color = c("Red", "Green", "Blue", "Green", "Purple", "Red"),
Year = c(1999, 2008, 2010, 2018, 2017, 2018),
License = c("123ABC", "544HGB", "923LWD", "443JFD", "889WER", "932OIF"))

df2 <- data.frame(Color = c("White", "Green", "Black", "Silver", "Purple", "Blue"),
Year = c(2013, 2008, 2004, 2012, 2017, 2019),
License = c("342UDD", "544HGB", "398KJX", "654KIR", "889WER", "874SSD"))
```

I want R to loop through df2, and every time it encounters a value in the license column that is **not** present in the license column of df1, it should append the entire row containing that license value from df2 to the top of df1 (i.e. make it the top row). Can anyone advise on the right way to do this?

Comment: Are those supposed to have three columns? As you've pasted it, they have 1 row and 18 columns. (Perhaps add `c(` and `)`?)

Comment: Yes, my apologies, thanks for spotting that. I forgot c(), just went back and added that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `anti_join` to get rows in `df2` that are not in `df1` and bind them with `df1`.

```
library(dplyr)
result <- bind_rows(df1, anti_join(df2, df1, by = 'License'))
result

#    Color Year License
#1     Red 1999  123ABC
#2   Green 2008  544HGB
#3    Blue 2010  923LWD
#4   Green 2018  443JFD
#5  Purple 2017  889WER
#6     Red 2018  932OIF
#7   White 2013  342UDD
#8   Black 2004  398KJX
#9  Silver 2012  654KIR
#10   Blue 2019  874SSD
```

Comment: Good point, I hadn't considered just doing a join. Going to try this now.

Answer (score 1):

### Base R

```r
rbind(df2[ ! df2$License %in% df1$License, ], df1)
#     Color Year License
# 1   White 2013  342UDD
# 3   Black 2004  398KJX
# 4  Silver 2012  654KIR
# 6    Blue 2019  874SSD
# 11    Red 1999  123ABC
# 2   Green 2008  544HGB
# 31   Blue 2010  923LWD
# 41  Green 2018  443JFD
# 5  Purple 2017  889WER
# 61    Red 2018  932OIF
```

---

Data

```r
df1 <- structure(list(Color = c("Red", "Green", "Blue", "Green", "Purple", "Red"), Year = c(1999, 2008, 2010, 2018, 2017, 2018), License = c("123ABC", "544HGB", "923LWD", "443JFD", "889WER", "932OIF")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
df2 <- structure(list(Color = c("White", "Green", "Black", "Silver", "Purple", "Blue"), Year = c(2013, 2008, 2004, 2012, 2017, 2019), License = c("342UDD", "544HGB", "398KJX", "654KIR", "889WER", "874SSD")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: And thanks to you for this as well, going to try both your suggestion and Ronak Shah's